# limiting a touch event in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, sprite, coronasdk

Kind of desperate here. I'm trying to make a runner game in Corona SDK and I fail in making a transition from jumping animation to running (back after a jump).

```
local function touched(event)     
if(event.phase == "began")then

char.accel = monster.accel + 20
char:prepare("jumping")
char:play()
else


char:prepare("running")
char:play()     

end     
end
```

In this code if the playing person keeps touching screen the animation of jumping keeps repeating on ground, is there a way to limit the touching event in time?

Also tried implementing the animations via another construction:

```
     if(onGround) then
           if(wasOnGround) then

           else
                monster:prepare("running")
                monster:play()
           end
      else
           monster:prepare("jumping")
           monster:play()
      end
```

But the jump animation for some reason displays only the first frame.

Any help would be immensely appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You have two viable options here;

1) If the jump is always going to take the same amount of time you could use a timer to prevent the user from jumping again until you know they will have landed. (The timer could change a variable or even remove and re-add the event listener, either would work.)

Or

2) Do similar to what you look to be doing above - add a collision listener on the player so that when it hits the ground a flag, eg, player.canJump is set to true and set it to false as soon as you start the jump animation. When the character hits ht ground again set it back to true and play the running animation again.